# select count(*) wrong result, cache or what?

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework

i have a sql query where i count the number of rows

```
SELECT count(*) AS `nr` FROM `ordine` WHERE (ditta_id = '3') AND (YEAR(`data`) = '2012') AND (stato = 'approvato' or stato = 'consegnato') LIMIT 1
```

I update some row changing stato into 'approvato', sometimes count() gives me the right number, sometimes it gives me the old number

Here is a piece of my logs:

```
2012-03-23T10:42:45+01:00 DEBUG (7): Row id = 1809
2012-03-23T10:42:45+01:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT count(*) AS `nr` FROM `ordine` WHERE (ditta_id = '3') AND (YEAR(`data`) = '2012') AND (stato = 'approvato' or stato = 'consegnato') LIMIT 1
2012-03-23T10:42:45+01:00 DEBUG (7): Result = 140
...change stato into 'approvato' thus count must give me 141 next time, requery the row, check changes are saved


2012-03-23T10:44:52+01:00 DEBUG (7): Row id = 1810
2012-03-23T10:44:52+01:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT count(*) AS `nr` FROM `ordine` WHERE (ditta_id = '3') AND (YEAR(`data`) = '2012') AND (stato = 'approvato' or stato = 'consegnato') LIMIT 1
2012-03-23T10:44:52+01:00 DEBUG (7): Result = 140 ?!!! why not 141?
```

ditta_id, agente_id, stato are indexes

I am using Zend Framework 1.11.11 and MySQL 5.1.49-3

Comment: Are you you're not changing the value from a row that already meets the counting criteria? You don't show enough information to really assess that.

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: @Vytautas - Both queries have `COUNT(*)`, so the same behaviour is exhibitted by both - NULL or NOT NULL makes no difference.

Comment: yes i am using MyISAM, so how do i get rid of the cache the article talks anout? changing count(*) to count(id) will fix it?

Comment: @max4ever - The article doesn't talk about a cache that fails to update. The article talks about `COUNT(*)` having different functionality from `COUNT(col)` (The latter does *not* count rows with a NULL in the column), and the relevance of Indexes, etc, to the query plan and performance. It is not relevant to your case. *[Have you been able to check the possibilities described in my answer? Can you show us the exact values of the row before and after your changes?]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the row you updated, I assume one of the following to be true...

- `ditta_id` is not `'3'`
- `YEAR(data)` is not `'2012'`
- `stato` was already `'approvato'`
- `stato` was already `'consegnato'`
- The new value in `stato` has a typo

Are you able to show us these fields before and after you change the `stato` field?